# How to build raspberry pi cluster environment with Android Things?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

How to build raspberry pi cluster environment with Android Things.

I have seen couple of posts on various sites/forums, that we can be able to build clustered environment with Raspberry Pi and Raspbian OS  via network switch card using Ethernet Cable.

It is possible to build same thing in Android Things. If it is not, is there any another way?

What is LowWPAN with Android Things.

[Link for reference, for RPi Clustered Env](https://makezine.com/projects/build-a-compact-4-node-raspberry-pi-cluster/)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to apply for Android things, but after thinking of it's, the hardware is the same, and the operation of Android is base on a Linux. You may even try all of this just like a Linux things.
An Android doesn't have a terminal for installing the Linux apps or compiled a program. But you can install an Android terminal emulator like Term*x for installing, configuring your network, or compiling a program.

Maybe Android can't have a same result like a Linux OS or it can be anything like what you want.
Back to Android, I think that's the one I was looking for a program to have a different result, and Android UI is created for anyone who wants to help their own lives with a smart phone.

So simple to use for anyone who doesn't know about computer things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer